# Error runing npm start (expo) - error listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::19000 - But it looks like the program itself is using such port

Tags: react-native, expo, npm-start, metro-bundler

I've lost two days now trying to find a solution for my problem with no success. I hope someone can help me out!

Since I upgraded my Expo yesterday, I can't open my project running **npm start** / **expo start**.

**The error is: error listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::19000**

[image]

I read the I should find out what was running in this port and kill it.

So I ran netstat -ano -p tcp to search for the PID.

However, I notice that **before running npm start this port wasn't shown in the list**, as you can see in the following image:

[image]

It's only after running npm start that it appears. Even then, there's no PID.

[image]

How can I fix this?

If in one hand I need to kill the process that is using the port but in the other hand it looks like to program itself is using the port.

Comment: Did you try to change your port to another one?

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying! I didn't change the port. What I did was run npm audit and updated / added the packages reported there. Now, metro is starting with QR code and all, so no problem with the port. However, a new error has occurred and I'm trying to figure that out: Unable to resolve "./prebuilt.rn-20822517.js" from "node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\rn\bundle.js". I've delete node_modules and ran npm install but the error persists. Would you have any idea that could help?

Comment: try to clear cache with npm start -- --reset-cache or expo start -c

Comment: Thanks, that helped. But I got a new error. I fixed that one and got another one (unbelievable, I know). So I start from scratch and this time I did not run npm audit. I found https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-42-579aee2348b6 and followed the updating process. Then you guess it, a new error... but now regarding to the Apploading component, so I replaced the old version with its own package (I was using from 'expo'). With that, the app finally opened. Of course, it still has some break points but at least is opening, which makes a little easier to fix. Thank you so much for your time!!!

Answer (score 0):

As this problem started after upgrading expo, I followed the upgrading process explained in https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-42-579aee2348b6.

Then, I got a new error regarding to { AppLoading } from 'expo', because now it has its own package, so I installed that and the App finally opened.

Still, it didn't fix all of my problems, as the AppLoading for example now creates many timeouts, each with a huge amount of seconds, creating many warnings like:

*Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground.
(Saw setTimeout with duration 418605ms).*

Another break that I've noticed is related with the image picker.

So for now, I'm trying to fix theses...